# Running nmake in powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, nmake

I am working on a powershell script, the script is calling a .bat file within .ps1 to run nmake which doesn't make sense to me, so I wish to move everything in one ps script, adding nmake to the script raise this error `The term 'NMAKE' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file...`. Is there anyway to run nmake from powershell?

Comment: Either add the nmake folder to the PATH environmental variable or give the full path to nmake.exe. (Put a `&` in front, if you have quotes around the location e.g. `& "C:\path\to\nmake.exe"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the file path to your executable if it is not in your PATH environment variable. e.g.:

```
& 'Path\to\nmake.exe' /arg1 pass /arg2 in
```

Comment: And what if a thirdparty powershell script uses nmake, but can't find it? No what to set a path in front of its calls...

Comment: @Sandburg You modify `$Env:PATH` to include the directory containing the third-party executable.